# PHP Problem with Nested for loop in chunk parts

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-loops

I try to do a nested for to process a for in blocks, everything works fine when I have values of 32 but when I put a total of 31 the 4th block is not processed. what could be the problem?

The for loop should not use Range because of a memory problem.

```
 $start = 1; //170003
    $total = 32;
    $chunksize=10;
    $block = 1;
    for ($i=$start; $i <= $total; $block++){
        echo "Block: ".$block."/".($total/$chunksize).PHP_EOL;

        for ($j=0; $j < $chunksize; $j++){
            //if($i === $total) break;
            echo "[".$block."] ".$i."/".$total." [Rest: ".($total-$i)."] " .PHP_EOL;

            if($i === $total) break;
            $i++;
        }

        echo "------------------------------".PHP_EOL;
        if($i === $total) break;
    }
```

Ourput:

```
Block: 1/3.2
[1] 1/32 [Rest: 31]
[1] 2/32 [Rest: 30]
[1] 3/32 [Rest: 29]
[1] 4/32 [Rest: 28]
[1] 5/32 [Rest: 27]
[1] 6/32 [Rest: 26]
[1] 7/32 [Rest: 25]
[1] 8/32 [Rest: 24]
[1] 9/32 [Rest: 23]
[1] 10/32 [Rest: 22]
------------------------------
Block: 2/3.2
[2] 11/32 [Rest: 21]
[2] 12/32 [Rest: 20]
[2] 13/32 [Rest: 19]
[2] 14/32 [Rest: 18]
[2] 15/32 [Rest: 17]
[2] 16/32 [Rest: 16]
[2] 17/32 [Rest: 15]
[2] 18/32 [Rest: 14]
[2] 19/32 [Rest: 13]
[2] 20/32 [Rest: 12]
------------------------------
Block: 3/3.2
[3] 21/32 [Rest: 11]
[3] 22/32 [Rest: 10]
[3] 23/32 [Rest: 9]
[3] 24/32 [Rest: 8]
[3] 25/32 [Rest: 7]
[3] 26/32 [Rest: 6]
[3] 27/32 [Rest: 5]
[3] 28/32 [Rest: 4]
[3] 29/32 [Rest: 3]
[3] 30/32 [Rest: 2]
------------------------------
Block: 4/3.2
[4] 31/32 [Rest: 1]
[4] 32/32 [Rest: 0]
------------------------------
```

> $total = 32; //Is OK
>
> $total = 31; // I don`t see Block 4

Thanks !!

Comment: The problem is that `$block` starts at `1`, and increases by `10` for each block. Therefor, at the end of the third block, `$block` is `31`. This triggers your `if($i === $total) break`, so no further processing occurs.

Comment: @ObsidianAge when it starts with 0 and I put the total at 40, the number 40 is not shown. :S

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it, thanks for the answers :)

```
  $start = 0;
    $total = 10;
    $chunksize=10;
    $block = 1;
    while ($start <= $total){

        echo "Block: ".$block."/".ceil($total/($chunksize-1)).PHP_EOL;

        if($start+$chunksize <= $total){
            $limit = $start+$chunksize;
        }else{
            $limit = $total+1;
        }

        for ($start; $start < $limit; $start++){
           echo "[".$block."] ".$start."/".$total." [Rest: ".($total-$start)."] " .PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo "------------------------------".PHP_EOL;

        $block++;
    }
```